# How do I infinitely loop this program in python?

Tags: python, calculator

Alright, I'm just starting to learn python, and have no idea where else to pose this question. I wrote this calculator and it works.

```
a,b=input("Enter two numbers (sperated by a comma): ")
operator=raw_input("Do you want to add, subtract, multiply, or divide? ")
if operator=="divide":
    print "Your answer is", a / b
if operator=="multiply":
    print "Your answer is", a * b
if operator=="add":
    print "Your answer is", a + b
if operator=="subtract":
    print "Your answer is", a - b    
repeat=raw_input("Do you want to perform another calculation(yes or no)? ")
```

Now, I want to know how to start this program all over again if the input is yes. I searched for an answer, but I couldn't figure out the command for looping the entire thing. Like in while loops, you have to give a command after the condition but what is that command? ples halp.

Comment: Can put true as condition

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it in a `while` loop:

```
repeat = "yes"
while repeat.lower().strip() == 'yes':
    a,b=input("Enter two numbers (sperated by a comma): ")
    operator=raw_input("Do you want to add, subtract, multiply, or divide? ")
    if operator=="divide":
        print "Your answer is", a / b
    if operator=="multiply":
        print "Your answer is", a * b
    if operator=="add":
        print "Your answer is", a + b
    if operator=="subtract":
        print "Your answer is", a - b    
    repeat=raw_input("Do you want to perform another calculation(yes or no)? ")
```

This will loop as long as the answer is 'yes' (case-insensitive).  The initial 'repeat' is to guarantee the loop runs at least once.

By the way, you can turn your `if` test into a dict:

```
import operator
ops = {'divide': operator.div,
       'multiply': operator.mul,
       'add': operator.add,
       'subtract': operator.sub}
repeat = "yes"
while repeat.lower().strip() == 'yes':
    a,b=input("Enter two numbers (sperated by a comma): ")
    operator=raw_input("Do you want to add, subtract, multiply, or divide? ").lower().strip()
    if operator not in ops:
        print 'Invalid operator:', operator
        continue
    print "Your answer is", ops[operator](a,b)
    repeat=raw_input("Do you want to perform another calculation(yes or no)? ")
```

Comment: A nitpick: I would use `if repeat.lower().strip() in 'yes': ...` - many programs support using just "y" instead of "yes"

Comment: I thought of that, but the question asked specifically asked for "(yes or no)", so that is what I set as a valid answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
while True:
    a,b=input("Enter two numbers (sperated by a comma): ")
    operator=raw_input("Do you want to add, subtract, multiply, or divide? ")
    if operator=="divide":
        print "Your answer is", a / b
    if operator=="multiply":
        print "Your answer is", a * b
    if operator=="add":
        print "Your answer is", a + b
    if operator=="subtract":
        print "Your answer is", a - b    
    repeat=raw_input("Do you want to perform another calculation(yes or no)? ")
    if repeat == 'no':
        break
```

While True continues looping forever, it can be broken by the keyword break (It breaks out of the nearest loop(for or while)).

When processing input from the user to determine a condition, it's preferable to check if the input from the user starts with "y" (yes) or starts with "n" (no), since the user might input y instead of yes and he might mess with the capitalization, here's a code that implements this:

```
while True:
    a,b=input("Enter two numbers (sperated by a comma): ")
    operator=raw_input("Do you want to add, subtract, multiply, or divide? ")
    if operator=="divide":
        print "Your answer is", a / b
    if operator=="multiply":
        print "Your answer is", a * b
    if operator=="add":
        print "Your answer is", a + b
    if operator=="subtract":
        print "Your answer is", a - b    
    repeat=raw_input("Do you want to perform another calculation(yes or no)? ")
    if repeat.lower.startswith('n'):
        break
```

"repeat" is a string, it has a method(Similiar to a function) called "lower", this method returns the lowercase representation of the string, then you can check if that lowercase representation(Also a string) starts with the letter "n" by using another method called startswith.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

You can use while True: with this the code written inside the for loop 
will execute infinitely,
To stop execution you can use Ctrl + C 

while True:
    a,b=input("Enter two numbers (sperated by a comma): ")
    operator=raw_input("Do you want to add, subtract, multiply, or divide? ")
    if operator=="divide":
        print "Your answer is", a / b
    if operator=="multiply":
        print "Your answer is", a * b
    if operator=="add":
        print "Your answer is", a + b
    if operator=="subtract":
        print "Your answer is", a - b    
    repeat=raw_input("Do you want to perform another calculation(yes or no)? ")
    if repeat == "no":
        break
```

Comment: This just continues looping forever even if the user have replied with "no" to repeat

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while True:    
    a,b=input("Enter two numbers (sperated by a comma): ")
    operator=raw_input("Do you want to add, subtract, multiply, or divide? ")
    if operator=="divide":
        print "Your answer is", a / b
    if operator=="multiply":
        print "Your answer is", a * b
    if operator=="add":
        print "Your answer is", a + b
    if operator=="subtract":
        print "Your answer is", a - b    
    repeat=raw_input("Do you want to perform another calculation(yes or no)? ")
    if repeat == "no":
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in repeat.upper():
   a,b=input("Enter two numbers (sperated by a comma): ")
   operator=raw_input("Do you want to add, subtract, multiply, or 
   divide? ")
   if operator=="divide":
      print "Your answer is", a / b
   if operator=="multiply":
      print "Your answer is", a * b
   if operator=="add":
      print "Your answer is", a + b
   if operator=="subtract":
      print "Your answer is", a - b    
   if oper == repeat:
      break
```

it will loop untill the certain condition true